# Where to check for 403 in a Django CBV?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am making a basic app to teach beginners.  Each user can write notes, but I want to make it so that a user cannot view or update a different user's notes.

I have the following view, but I had to repeat myself.

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

...

class NoteUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()

        if self.object.owner != self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied

        return super(NoteUpdate, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()

        if self.object.owner != self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied

        return super(NoteUpdate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I feel like there is probably a way to do this without repeating myself.  Yeah, I could write a method like this and call it from both:

```
def check_permission(self):
   if self.object.owner != self.request.user:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

But what I really mean is am I overriding the wrong methods?  Is there a more traditional way to do this?  It feels a little weird overriding .get() and .post()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question: Overriding `.get()` and `.post()` is fine, since for security and integrity reasons, you would want both your `get()` and `post()` views to validate before displaying and especially modifying data. Now, if you want to refactor doing this in get or post, there are 2 easy ways of doing this:

Primary (Model Method):

models.py

```
class Model(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...

    def deny_if_not_owner(self, user):
        if self.owner != user:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return self.owner
```

views.py

```
class NoteUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()

        self.object.deny_if_not_owner(request.user)

        return super(NoteUpdate, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()

        self.object.deny_if_not_owner(request.user)

        return super(NoteUpdate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

///////

Alternative (Mixin):

Creating a Mixin would allow you to easily add this code to many classes if you see yourself using this validation again in the future.

```
class DenyWrongUserMixin(object):
    def get(self):
        if self.object.owner != self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super(DenyWrongUserMixin, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

    def post(self):
        if self.object.owner != self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super(DenyWrongUserMixin, self).post(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then:

```
class NoteUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, DenyWrongUserMixin, UpdateView):

    ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Comment: I thought you were trying to refactor for scalable use. I updated my answer to directly answer your question of "Is overriding `get` and `post` correct - my answer is yes. You can see my modified answer to see why, and the primary solution shows how to bring some of the validation to the model level to reduce code in the views, while allowing easy implementation later.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer.  That's a good reminder about making thick models and thin views, although it does rub me the wrong way to put HTTP response stuff in the model.  (I deleted my previous comment since it doesn't apply with your new comment about mixins, although now I see you replied to it.  Sorry!).

Answer (score 0):

You can override the get method or the get_queryset method. The get_queryset will raise a 404 if the logged in user is not the owner.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(NoteUpdate, self).get_queryset()
    return qs.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

or you can just override the get method since it will be called first and then raise PermissionDenied, so no reason to override the post method as well.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    if self.object.owner != self.request.user:
        raise PermissionDenied
    return super(NoteUpdate, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then you can create a mixin and extend your views from the mixin to avoid the duplication.

Comment: If I override GET but don't override POST I understand that I will protect against an accident (since they can't view the form page to submit it via the web) but couldn't someone still be malicious?